# Speech Synthesis with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Прошу помочь с реализацией данного примера = [Speech Synthesis with ASP.NET and HTML5](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/speech-synthesis-with-asp-net-and-html5)

приложение WebForms 
в папке App_Code создал класс

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

/// <summary>
/// Сводное описание для SpeechSynthesizer
/// </summary>
[ConstructorNeedsTag(false)]
public class SpeechSynthesizer : HtmlGenericControl, ICallbackEventHandler
{
    private readonly System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer synth = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

    public SpeechSynthesizer()
        : base("audio")
    {
        this.Age = VoiceAge.NotSet;
        this.Gender = VoiceGender.NotSet;
        this.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        this.VoiceName = String.Empty;
        this.Ssml = false;
    }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public String VoiceName { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(100)]
    public Int32 Volume { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public Int32 Rate { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CultureInfoConverter))]
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(VoiceGender.NotSet)]
    public VoiceGender Gender { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(VoiceAge.NotSet)]
    public VoiceAge Age { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public Boolean Ssml { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext = new SynchronizationContext();

        var sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        var reference = this.Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "text", String.Format("function(result){{ document.getElementById('{0}').src = result; document.getElementById('{0}').play(); }}", this.ClientID), String.Empty, true);
        var script = String.Format("\ndocument.getElementById('{0}').speak = function(text){{ {1} }};\n", this.ClientID, reference);

        if (sm != null)
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), String.Concat("speak", this.ClientID), String.Format("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {{ {0} }});\n", script), true);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), String.Concat("speak", this.ClientID), script, true);
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Attributes.Remove("class");
        this.Attributes.Remove("src");
        this.Attributes.Remove("preload");
        this.Attributes.Remove("loop");
        this.Attributes.Remove("autoplay");
        this.Attributes.Remove("controls");

        this.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "none";
        this.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] = "hidden";

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        this.synth.Dispose();

        base.Dispose();
    }

    #region ICallbackEventHandler Members

    String ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            this.synth.Rate = this.Rate;
            this.synth.Volume = this.Volume;
            this.synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.VoiceName) == false)
            {
                this.synth.SelectVoice(this.VoiceName);
            }
            else
            {
                this.synth.SelectVoiceByHints(this.Gender, this.Age, 0, this.Culture);
            }

            if (this.Ssml == false)
            {
                this.synth.Speak(this.Context.Items["data"] as String);
            }
            else
            {
                this.synth.SpeakSsml(this.Context.Items["data"] as String);
            }

            return (String.Concat("data:audio/wav;base64,", Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())));
        }
    }

    void ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
    {
        this.Context.Items["data"] = eventArgument;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

добавил тестовую страницу

```html
<%@ Page Async="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="speech.aspx.cs" Inherits="contact_speech" %>

  <%@ Register Assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Speech" TagPrefix="web" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSpeak(text) {
          document.getElementById('synthesizer').speak(text);
        }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
          <div>
            <web:SpeechSynthesizer runat="server" ID="synthesizer" Age="Adult" Gender="Male" Culture="en-US" Rate="0" Volume="100" />
            <input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
            <input type="button" value="Speak" onclick="onSpeak(this.form.text.value)" />
          </div>
          <%--<asp:Button ID="btVoice" runat="server" Text="ОЗВУЧИТЬ СОДЕРЖИМОЕ СТРАНИЦЫ" OnClick="btVoice_Click" />--%>
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

при построении приложения получаю ошибку

Предупреждение  1   Неизвестный элемент "SpeechSynthesizer". Это может произойти в случае ошибки компиляции на веб-сайте или отсутствия файла web.config.   \speech.aspx    21  22

прошу подсказать как исправить ошибку 
С уважением Юрий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте папку App_Code (и неймспейс Code - тоде). Это системная папка для старого типа проектов - Web Sites, которые компилировались полностью на лету. Могут возникнуть проблемы с видимостью классов из нее.

Как привести ваш пример в рабочий вид:

1. Перенесите файл с контролом из папки App_Code в папку с нейтральным именем, наприме Controls.
2. Проверьте в свойствах файла Build Action - если он выставлен в Content - поменяйте на Compile.
3. Задайте неймспейс для класса, например:

   ```
   namespace WebApplication9.Controls
   {
       ...
       [ConstructorNeedsTag(false)]
       public class SpeechSynthesizer : HtmlGenericControl, ICallbackEventHandler
       {
       ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Зарегистрируйте ваш нейсмпейс с префиксом `web:` в web.config:

   ```
   <system.web>
     <pages>
       <controls>
         <add assembly="WebApplication9" namespace="WebApplication9.Controls" 
           tagPrefix="web"/>
       </controls>
     </pages>
   ```
5. Уберите контрол со страницы. Сохраните ее.
6. Пересоберите проект.
7. Верните контрол на страницу. В designer-файле страницы появится строка вида

   ```
   protected global::WebApplication9.Controls.SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer;
   ```
8. Запускайте приложение и наслаждайтесь.

Для проекта типа Web Site (без csproj и с компиляцией на лету):

1. Оставить файл контрола в App_Code, но добавить namespace.
2. В web.config зарегистрировать namespace без указания assembly:

   ```
   <add namespace="WebApplication9.Controls" tagPrefix="web"/>
   ```

Но в целом - Web Forms медленно умирает. Смотрите в сторону MVC.

Comment: В том то и все дело что проект - приложение WebForms (старого типа проектов - Web Sites). Как для этого вида сайта реализовать такую возможность? То что Вы описали выдает туже ошибку ... Переходить на MVC - если это единственный выход из этой ситуации - прошу прислать мне на почту (krakoss@mail.ru) данный проект реализованный на MVC (если Вас не затруднит) - сам ведь буду долго реализовывать. С уважением Юрий

Comment: Т.е. у вас проект совсем-совсем древнего типа, под 2005-ю студию, от которого MS избавился еще в 2008-ом году? Или у вас Web Application с Web Forms - т.е. есть csproj файл, который вы открываете в студии? Решение из ответа - для csproj/web application. Если оно у вас не сработало - значит вы какой-то шаг пропустили, или где-то ошиблись с namespace или именем assembly. Залейте куда-нибудь исходники, или приведите в вопросе минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5yzA/Zb7euybC3) - выложил на майле ... Но в целом - Web Forms медленно умирает. Смотрите в сторону MVC ... точно поставленная задача - буду изучать

Comment: (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/LFCS/EgUSsWpUJ) вот такие у меня веб сайты

Comment: @ЮрийКосенко взял ваш проект (по первой ссылке), вернул контрол в App_Code, убрал упоминание assembly из web.config - и контрол нормально подхватился на странице. Звука, правда, нет, но это уже какая-то другая проблема.

Comment: Не смог выполнить то что Вы изложили в вашем ответе - выложите проект для оценки его работы

Comment: @ЮрийКосенко https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8o4nih57dbuzaq/TTS.zip?dl=0

Comment: спасибо - перешел на MVC